# RestFul Webservices Authentication in Android program?

Tags: android, web-services, rest

I am very new to Android rest web-services I want connect Rest web-services from my android program for that I write the following code :

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://***********:8000/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/z_customer_lookup1/800/z_customer_lookup1/z_customer_lookup1_bind&sap-user=*******&sap-password=********");
```

but when I am running this code I am getting the logon Error message how can i provide authentication in Android Rest Web-services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code for using http post method  : 
`List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("request", "login"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_name", user_name));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));`

```
            HttpParams params = client.getParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 3000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 3000);


            HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httppost);
            result=EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());`
```

Comment: i want  get the the data from server ?

Comment: @user1581386 you have to add your url at HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);